# Map won't render headless

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

i have a working nodejs/puppeteer solution for rendering a map to screenshot. the code works great with an interactive/visible browser, but does not render the page when run headless.  if i drop back to an ancient mapbox (build 25) then it does render headless but mapbox is missing other functionality in that old build that i need.

is there anything i can do to make this work.  code to repro below.

```
    (async() => {
console.log("test starting");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,userDataDir: "data"});
const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
await page.goto('file://map.html');
await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("#sync").textContent.includes("sync")');
await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 480 });
await page.screenshot({path: 'map.png'});
await browser.close();
})();

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:800px; height:480px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<div id='sync'></div>
<script>
const outputContainer = document.getElementById('sync');
mapboxgl.accessToken = '**token**';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.3351,47.6080],
    zoom: 7
});
map.once('idle', (e) => {
    console.log("map loaded");
    outputContainer.innerHTML += `sync<br>`;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i found via a resolved github issue that adding the map option "preserveDrawingBuffer: true" allows the tiles to render.  However the "idle" even is never fired in headless mode.